# SharePoint List Validation Not Working

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, list, calculated-column-formula, validation

I have this list validation expression:

```
=IF([Enrolled], IF(ISBLANK([Email Address]), FALSE, TRUE), TRUE)
```

But its not triggering any validation. I also tried some simpler validation expressions:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Email Address]), FALSE, TRUE)
```

as well as:

```
=ISBLANK([Email Address])
```

with no luck.

[image: heres a screenshot of the formula]

Comment: What is the type of `Enrolled` field ?

Answer (score 0):

If `[Enrolled]` column is of type Yes/No (Boolean), the given formula should work for you.

If not, try using semicolons instead of commas like:

```
=IF([Enrolled]; IF(ISBLANK([Email Address]); FALSE; TRUE); TRUE)
```

If `[Enrolled]` column is of type text, use:

```
=IF([Enrolled]="", TRUE, IF(ISBLANK([Email Address]), FALSE, TRUE))
```

If `[Enrolled]` column is of type date & time, use:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Enrolled]), TRUE, IF(ISBLANK([Email Address]), FALSE, TRUE))
```

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (it is based on language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).
2. Use correct *display name* of your SharePoint columns in above formula.
3. Wrap column names inside `[]` if your column name has space in it. For example: `[My Column Name]`.

**Official Documentations**:

1. [Calculated Field Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v%3Doffice.14))